How to Import Cookies Extracted from Chrome Using Cookie Editor into a MinBrowser?
I've extracted cookie from chrome using cookie editor extension in json format. I'm now trying to import these cookies into Min browser that does not support extensions
what I've done is access the developer tool in Min browser and and go to application tab and I found cookies section there but I'm not sure how to use it
What I need help with:

How can I import the cookies from the JSON format(or any format) into my Min browser?
If direct import isn’t possible, what alternative methods are available to use these cookies in the Min browser?

